# python - No module named 'pywidevine.L3'

Tags: python, homebrew, widevine

Have been trying a python script which has required a bunch of additional modules, that I've installed according to the error messages, leading to the next one until I got stuck. The specific error is: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pywidevine.L3"

Have already installed "pywidevine". Did this on a whim without really knowing what to do when the previous module error message called for "pywidevine.L3.cdm.formats.widevine_pssh_data_pb2", after which this current module error message calling for "pywidevine.L3" comes up. Little to no idea what I'm actually doing or how these things work – only trying to get a script to work.

---

edit: https://github.com/JockeyJarus/AppleMusic-DownloaderV2

how to use:
python applemusic.py [applemusic link]

Comment: What's the very minimum amount of code you need to reproduce this error? Please [edit] the question. See how to create a [mcve] for more ideas.

Answer (score 0):

The error is correct there is no module called L3 in pywidevine. please refer to the source code of the [package repository](https://github.com/rlaphoenix/pywidevine/tree/master/pywidevine). Please make edit to your question so that we can know what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Hello! I made an edit. 
Trying to download from applemusic and have really only executed "python applemusic.py" and installed modules that were not found one by one. Can't get around pywidevine.L3